Spark Structured Streaming join between static and streaming dataframes
I was reading about spark structured streaming joins and came across the supported types of joins for static to streaming dataset. I have a question, why it is not supported since as far as I understand at a given point in time the streaming dataframe behaves like static and when we join static with streaming it should work. If it supports following

Left outer join when the left side is a streaming DataFrame
Right outer join when the right side is a streaming DataFrame

If we change the direction of the dataframes it is not supported and full outer join is also not supported. Let me know what i'm missing here. Essentially I want to understand what is the reason it is not supported what exactly happens which prevents spark from supporting it.

Using the example of a left outer join, where the left table is a stream, and the right table is static. Let's say our left (streaming) table looks like this, at the time you want to perform a right outer join.



ID
Value




1
Value 1


3
Value 3



Now, let's say the right (static) dataframe looks like this:



ID
OtherValue




1
OtherValue 1


2
OtherValue 2


3
OtherValue 3



If we could freeze the streaming table in time, and do the join, it'd look like this:



ID_x
Value
ID_y
OtherValue




1
Value 1
1
OtherValue 1


NULL
NULL
2
OtherValue 2


3
Value 3
3
OtherValue 3



Now the stream delivers the following record:



ID
Value




2
Value 2



How then should this be joined? The only option is to update values in the join, not simply append. Because streaming data is designed to be append-only, this breaks the mechanics of the join. One of the rows in the join (the second row where ID_x is NULL and ID_y is 2), would have to be purged from the dataset, but it's already been delivered in the join.
This is why it's not possible. It's less of a technical challenge, and more of a logical one.
